# can't build my app apk with buildozer in Google Colab?

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer, kivymd

I watched a short tutorial with deploying kivy/kivymd apps to apk, i have done everything but mine won't build,

```
[DEBUG]:    <-------------> 0% INITIALIZING [35ms]
[DEBUG]:    <-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [135ms]> root project > Resolve dependencies of :classpath<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [235ms]> root project > Resolve files of :classpath<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [335ms]> root project<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [436ms]<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [535ms]<-------------> 2% EXECUTING [635ms]> :preDebugBuild<===----------> 28% EXECUTING [736ms]> :mergeDebugResources<====---------> 34% EXECUTING [835ms]> :processDebugManifest<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [935ms]> :processDebugResources<======-------> 48% EXECUTING [1s]> :compileDebugJavaWithJavac<======-------> 48% EXECUTING [2s]
[DEBUG]:    > Task :compileDebugJavaWithJavac
[DEBUG]:    Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[DEBUG]:    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[DEBUG]:    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[DEBUG]:    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    <========-----> 65% EXECUTING [2s]> :mergeDebugAssets<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [3s]<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [4s]<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [5s]<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [6s]<========-----> 68% EXECUTING [6s]> :transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug<========-----> 68% EXECUTING [7s]<=========----> 74% EXECUTING [7s]> :transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug<==========---> 77% EXECUTING [7s]> :mergeDebugJniLibFolders<==========---> 80% EXECUTING [8s]> :transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug<==========---> 82% EXECUTING [8s]> :transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug
[DEBUG]:    > Task :transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug
[DEBUG]:    /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip:/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/sto__armeabi-v7a/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/debug/0/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup: File format not recognized
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    Unable to strip library '1' due to error /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip returned from '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/sto__armeabi-v7a/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/debug/0/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup', packaging it as is.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    <============-> 94% EXECUTING [8s]> :packageDebug<============-> 94% EXECUTING [9s]
[DEBUG]:    > Task :packageDebug FAILED
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * What went wrong:
[DEBUG]:    Execution failed for task ':packageDebug'.
[DEBUG]:    > org.gradle.tooling.BuildException (no error message)
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * Try:
[DEBUG]:    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
[DEBUG]:    Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[DEBUG]:    See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    BUILD FAILED in 10s
[DEBUG]:    27 actionable tasks: 27 executed
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    <-------------> 0% WAITING> IDLE
Exception in thread background thread for pid 156314:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1637, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 2561, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 2265, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 865, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/sto__armeabi-v7a/gradlew assembleDebug

  STDOUT:

<-------------> 0% INITIALIZING [35ms]
<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [135ms]> root project > Resolve dependencies of :classpath<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [235ms]> root project > Resolve files of :classpath<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [335ms]> root project<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [436ms]<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [535ms]<-------------> 2% EXECUTING [635ms]> :preDebugBuild<===----------> 28% EXECUTING [736ms]> :mergeDebugResources<====---------> 34% EXECUTING [835ms]> :processDebugManifest<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [935ms]> :processDebugResources<======-------> 48% EXECUTING [1s]> :compileDebugJavaWithJavac<======-------> 48% EXECUTING [2s]
> Task :compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.


<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [2s]> :mergeDebugAssets<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [3s]<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [4s]<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [5s]<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [6s]<========-----> 68% EXECUTING [6s]> :transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug<========-----> 68% EXECUTING [7s]<=========----> 74% EXECUTING [7s]> :transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug<==========---> 77% EXECUTING [7s]> :mergeDebugJniLibFolders<==========---> 80% EXECUTING [8s]> :transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug<==========---> 82% EXECUTING [8s]> :transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug
> Task :transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug
/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip:/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/sto__armeabi-v7a/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/debug/0/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup: File format not recognized

Unable to strip library '1' due to error /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip returned from '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/sto__armeabi-v7a/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/debug/0/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup', packaging it as is.


<============-> 94% EXECUTING [8s]> :packageDebug<============-> 94% EXECUTING [9s]
> Task :packageDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':packageDebug'.
> org.gradle.tooling.BuildException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 10s
27 actionable tasks: 27 executed


<-------------> 0% WAITING> IDLE

  STDERR:


[INFO]:    STDOUT (last 20 lines of 40):
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.    
    
* What went wrong:  
Execution failed for task ':packageDebug'.  
> org.gradle.tooling.BuildException (no error message)  
    
* Try:  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.    
    
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org  
    
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0. 
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.   
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings   
    
BUILD FAILED in 10s 
27 actionable tasks: 27 executed    
    
    
<-------------> 0% WAITING> IDLE
[INFO]:    STDERR:
    
[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/sto__armeabi-v7a && /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/sto__armeabi-v7a/gradlew assembleDebug

[WARNING]: ERROR: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/sto__armeabi-v7a/gradlew failed!
WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Applying Java source code patches...
Applying patch: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Applying Java source code patches...
Applying patch: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --debug --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name sto --name STO --version 0.1 --package org.test.sto --minsdk 21 --ndk-api 21 --private /content/.buildozer/android/app --android-entrypoint org.kivy.android.PythonActivity --android-apptheme @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar --orientation portrait --window --copy-libs --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir="/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     CUDNN_VERSION = '8.0.4.30'
#     PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL = 'NO'
#     LD_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64'
#     CLOUDSDK_PYTHON = 'python3'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     HOSTNAME = '4bc76ba1c227'
#     OLDPWD = '/'
#     CLOUDSDK_CONFIG = '/content/.config'
#     NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 'all'
#     DATALAB_SETTINGS_OVERRIDES = '{"kernelManagerProxyPort":6000,"kernelManagerProxyHost":"172.28.0.3","jupyterArgs":["--ip=\\"172.28.0.2\\""],"debugAdapterMultiplexerPath":"/usr/local/bin/dap_multiplexer"}'
#     ENV = '/root/.bashrc'
#     PAGER = 'cat'
#     NCCL_VERSION = '2.7.8'
#     TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH = 'true'
#     JPY_PARENT_PID = '47'
#     NO_GCE_CHECK = 'True'
#     PWD = '/content'
#     HOME = '/root'
#     LAST_FORCED_REBUILD = '20210323'
#     CLICOLOR = '1'
#     DEBIAN_FRONTEND = 'noninteractive'
#     LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs'
#     GCE_METADATA_TIMEOUT = '0'
#     GLIBCPP_FORCE_NEW = '1'
#     TBE_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8008'
#     TERM = 'xterm-color'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     GCS_READ_CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_MB = '16'
#     PYTHONWARNINGS = 'ignore:::pip._internal.cli.base_command'
#     MPLBACKEND = 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
#     CUDA_VERSION = '11.0.3'
#     NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES = 'compute,utility'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     PYTHONPATH = '/env/python'
#     NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA = ('cuda>=11.0 brand=tesla,driver>=418,driver<419 '
 'brand=tesla,driver>=440,driver<441 brand=tesla,driver>=450,driver<451')
#     COLAB_GPU = '0'
#     GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW = '1'
#     PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/opt/bin'
#     LD_PRELOAD = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc.so.4'
#     GIT_PAGER = 'cat'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full
```

Here's my build spec:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Myapp

# (str) Package name
package.name = app

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,wav,gif

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,python-for-android,libffi

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug


    log with log_level = 2
```

please help! at first their was a warning that lld was not found, so i went ahead and installed it, now there's a new warning about Context python recipe found, please help

Comment: Did you found any solution

Answer (score 0):

If are using a 32-bit version of python it won't work and make sure the file is named main.py and in build.spec file don't name the application as my app I just changed the name of the app and it worked.
upload your main.py file to google colab and run these commands:

```
!pip install buildozer

!pip install cython==0.29.19
 
!pip install kivymd

!pip install python-for-android

!sudo apt install lld

!sudo apt-get install -y \
    python3-pip \
    build-essential \
    git \
    python3 \
    python3-dev \
    ffmpeg \
    libsdl2-dev \
    libsdl2-image-dev \
    libsdl2-mixer-dev \
    libsdl2-ttf-dev \
    libportmidi-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    zlib1g-dev

!sudo apt-get install -y \
    libgstreamer1.0 \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-good

!sudo apt-get install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev 
zlib1g-dev libssl-dev openssl libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev 
libreadline-dev libncursesw5-dev libffi-dev uuid-dev libffi6

!sudo apt-get install libffi-dev

!buildozer init

!buildozer -v android debug deploy run

!buildozer android clean
```